# What are examples of Cisco IOS Syslog level 0 (emergency) messages?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, syslog

What are examples of Cisco IOS Syslog level 0 (emergency) messages? I have never come across one, nor have I been able to google for one.

Comment: Removed off-topic request for a resource.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco has a large listing of Syslog Messages and Severity level here: [Syslog Messages](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/products-system-message-guides-list.html)

This list includes Syslog Messages for the following:

- IOS Software Release 15SY
- IOS Software Release 12.2SY
- IOS Software Release 12.2SX
- ASA Services Module

For the IOS Guides, you have to drill into the individual error messages to find the severity level.  The ASA has a [specific section](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/syslog-guide/syslogs/logsevp.html), breaking down the severity Level.

**Per Cisco documentation, the ASA IOS does not actually list any Severity 0 (Emergency) level messages.**  After a quick glance, I was not able to come up with any IOS Syslog messages with a Severity 0 (although, some may be found after some deep digging into the documentation).

Cisco does not call out any reason for lack of Severity 0 messages.  However, Cisco does allows users to reassign the severity of Syslog messages.  **I suspect the lack of default Severity 0 messages is to give users a custom level to which they can assign.**  The thought process could be that if a user needs to reassign a Syslog Message Severity Level, it must be very important and it will likely be assigned the highest severity level.